# Pi3 model B v2 no longer reads SD card!

Tags: pi-3, troubleshooting

I've had this pi for almost a year and have been using it recently for almost a month, and it used to work just fine. All of a sudden, the green LED stopped blinking "an indication I found out means it's not reading the SD card", and this has been the case for a couple of days now. I tried another SD card with a fresh image but to no avail...

Comment: Perhaps you can try a second Rpi to prove that the first one cannot read anything.

Comment: @tlfong01 i did..

Comment: Hi @Ahmed Magdy，Let me see: (1) Rpi A + Card X = Bad, (2) Rpi A + Card Y = Bad, (3) Rpi B + Card X = Good. (4) Conclusion: Rpi A is bad. (5) Now we need to find out why Rpi A is not reading Card X, Y, and possibly any other cards.  One of the many possible reasons is that Rpi's on board physical SD card reader or wiring is broken.  Is green LED blinking 4 times, or just dead?

Comment: @tlfong01 the green led doesn't blink at all, though the red one glows continuously as long as i connect it to the power source. all the other observations you mentioned in your comment apply to my case..

Comment: Beside the broken reader thing, can a blown polyfuse be the fault, as suggested by [the sticky on the same issue](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)??